# Javascript regex not working in Java

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I got this Javascript phone regex: 
`/^([\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/`

String "063-444-444" passes succesfully.

I tried to convert it to Java:

```
^([\\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \\.\\-])?([\\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\\)])?(\\[0-9 \\.\\-\\]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

The same String fails in Java. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't escaped it correctly. You don't need to escape the brackets (`[` and `]`) around the character classes.

Try:

```
^([\\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \\.\\-])?([\\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\\)])?([0-9 \\.\\-\\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

Comment: Thank you, I escaped [ and ] because I had a runtime exception "Unclosed character class near xxx". Anyway, this seems to work.